# Не выполняется конструктор

Tags: java, конструктор

Файл CleanBackupFolders.java:

```
import java.io.*;

public class CleanBackupFolders {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ...
        Settings IniFileObj = new Settings();
        ...
    }
}
```

Файл Settings.java:

```
public class Settings {
    public void Settings() {
        System.out.println("Constructor executed!");
    }
}
```

В первом классе не выполняется вызов конструктора для объекта. Если же после поставить строку

```
IniFileObj.Settings();
```

то все, что в этом конструкторе, исполняется. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

В вашем коде несколько проблем:

1. Вы не создали конструктор. Вы создали метод с именем как у конструктора, но дали ему возвращаемое значение, а конструктор оного не имеет.
2. Методы в Яве и (переменные тоже) принято именовать с маленькой буквы. Как раз из-за этого вы и ошиблись - конструктор от остальных методов отличается не только отсутствием возвращаемого значения, но и тем, что имя его начинается с большой буквы (точнее - полностью совпадает с именем класса).

Т.е. на самом деле вы вызываете сначала конструктор по умолчанию, который создаётся автоматически, если вы не создали к.-л. другой конструктор. После этого вы вызываете созданный вами обычный метод. Причём т.к. переменную вы создали не по правилам именования, т.е. с большой буквы, на первый взгляд ваш метод вообще выглядит статическим.

---

**Мораль:**

Если бы вы уважали конвенции именования, то ошибки бы у вас не возникло.

Comment: Убрал **void** - заработало! Спасибо за разъяснения. Насчет именований - я в курсе, тут просто упустил, исправлю.

Comment: По второму пункту - имя конструктора написано с большой буквы, так что тут все верно, вот имя экземпляра - да, не следовало соглашениям.